# Creating divs and getting content dynamically using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to display a list of some of a user's Facebook friends, with each friend getting their own `<div>`. This is what I'm trying to do:

```
for (var i=0;i<responseArray.length+1;i++){
   friend = response['data'][i];
   friends.push(friend.id);
   $('#sidebar').append('<div class="friendbox" id="'+friend.id+'"></div>');
   FB.api(
       "/"+friend.id+"/picture",
       {
           "redirect": false,
           "height": "100",
           "type": "square",
           "width": "100"
       },
       function (response) {
         if (response && !response.error) {
           $('#'+friend.id+'').append('<img class="friendpic" src="'+response['data']['url']+'">');
         }
       }
   );
   FB.api(
       "/"+friend.id+"",
       function (response) {
         if (response && !response.error) {
           console.log(response);
           $('#'+friend.id+'').append(response['first_name']);
         }
       }
   );
}
```

There's a problem though - the images and names aren't being placed into the `<div>` that I've specified them to be placed into. I think the loop moves on to the next iteration before the data has been received from Facebook and then when it is received, it's added to the wrong `<div>`.

Any ideas how to get it to stick the right content into the right containers?

Thanks

Comment: Your explanation for the error is correct. What attributes are in the response object?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Ennosigaeon, the attributes of the response object depend on whether it's fetching the picture or the first name.

Comment: Is it possible to get name and picture with a single request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know why you are making too many of facebook calls when it can all be done with a single call.

You have not mentioned anywhere about `responseArray`, but it is most probably the result from `/me/friends`. Now, the calls you are making inside the loop are not required at all.

First, change `/me/friends` to `/me/friends?fields=first_name` (you can add more fields if later required by comma-separating). Then inside your loop do this-

```
for (var i=0; i<response['data'].length; i++){
   friend = response['data'][i];
   friends.push(friend.id);
   $(document.body).append('<div class="friendbox" id="'+friend.id+'"></div>');
   $('#'+friend.id+'').append('<img class="friendpic" src="https://graph.facebook.com/'+friend.id+'/picture?height=100&width=100&type=square">');
   $('#'+friend.id+'').append(friend['first_name']);
}
```

where, `response` is the result of `/me/friends?fields=first_name`

That's it! :)